# Find all pairs $(x, y)$ such that $16^{x^{2}+y}+16^{x+y^{2}}=1 $

Tags: inequality, solution-verification, contest-math, exponential-function

> Find all pairs $(x, y)$ of real numbers such that
> $$
> 16^{x^{2}+y}+16^{x+y^{2}}=1
> $$

I know this question has been answered multiple times but i have another solution which i have  to validate.

So after taking $16^x16^y$ common from the equation we get

$$16^{x+y}=\dfrac{1}{16^{x(x-1)}+16^{y(y-1)}}$$

Now LHS is increasing while RHS is decreasing so equation can have at most one real root which can be find by putting x=y to get $(x, y)=(-1 / 2,-1 / 2)$ .

Anything wrong ?

Comment: Why is the RHS decreasing (in x)? In particular, what happens when $ x < \frac{1}{2}$, esp given that the solution involves $ x = - \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: What does it mean for a function in two variables to be increasing?

Comment: What do you mean by an increasing (and decreasing) function of two variables? What is the partial ordering on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: As $16=2^4$ is a power of $2,$

one of the solutions will be $$x^2+y=x+y^2=-\dfrac14$$

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore OP is essentially asking for solution verification, not for solutions to the original problem.

Comment: oops,i think i wrongly apply the fact that $a^x$ is increasing when $a>1$ ,thanks for pointing out.

Comment: @CalvinLin yes of course ,but now that the OP has got the mistake , this question   becomes  a duplicate

Answer (score 4):

I think your reasoning is wrong.

Why the right side decreases?

How you define decreasing for the function of two variables?

By AM-GM  $$1\geq2\sqrt{16^{x^2+y}\cdot16^{x+y^2}}=4^{x^2+y^2+x+y+\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt2^{(2x+1)^2+(2y+1)^2}\geq1,$$
which gives $$x=y=-\frac{1}{2}.$$